# Definition of a critical group of a graph

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory

I'm reading an introductory paper ([here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.04395.pdf)) on critical groups of graphs and came across this line:
$\text{cok(}L\text{)}\cong\mathbb{Z}\oplus K$, on page three. $L$ is defined as the Laplacian of a connected graph, cok is the cokernel of it, and $K$ is the critical group of the same graph. I have a rough idea of the cokernel, though if anyone could explain it more clearly it would help a lot. I also do not know what $\cong$ means in this context, nor the $\oplus$. I would appreciate clarification on any part of this definition!

Answer (score 1):

For a linear map (group homomorphism) $L:\mathbb Z^n\to\mathbb Z^n$, the cokernel is the quotient of the range of the homomorphism (which is $\mathbb Z^n$) by the image of $L$. The paper is asserting that the image of $L$ has rank $n-1$. The direct sum of groups $A$ and $B$, denoted by $A\oplus B$, is the group on the set $A\times B$ such that $(a_1,b_1)+(a_2,b_2)=(a_1+a_2,a_2+b_2)$. The paper is saying that the cokernel of $L$ is isomorphic ($\cong$) to the direct sum of $\mathbb Z$ and a finite abelian group $K$, which directly follows from the fact that the image has rank $n-1$.